# Array declaration in FORTRAN for beginners

Tags: arrays, fortran, declaration

This is a beginners question but I haven't found a comprehensive answer.

What are the differences (if any) of the following declarations?

```
CHARACTER(5) :: a
CHARACTER, DIMENSION (5) :: b
CHARACTER(LEN=5) :: c
CHARACTER :: d(5)
CHARACTER :: e*5
```

And: are all of these declarations possible with other types, e.g `REAL`?

Comment: only two of them are arrays

Comment: @Vladimir_F elaborate please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the type, `<type>,dimension(5) :: b` and `<type> :: b(5)` are identical and denote an array of length `5`. `<type>` can be e.g. `character`, `integer`, `real`, `logical`, etc.

`character(5)` is a short-hand of `character(len=5)` and declares a string of length `5`. If the length is omitted, it is assumed to be on. `character :: d(5)` is an array of five length-1 strings.

`character :: e*5` is an older variant to specify the string length.

`len` is intrinsic to strings (and makes no sence for e.g. floats). You can specify your own derived types to have an length `len`, though ("Parameterized derived types"). For integers and floats (and some others) you can specify the `kind` of the variable in a similar way.

For details consult the [Fortran 2008 Standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), Ch. 4.4.3.2 *"Character type specifier"*.

Comment: Keep editing! The answer is getting better and better :)

Answer (score 3):

Three of those declare a character variable that holds a string of 5 characters.  Two of them declare an array of 5 characters, each capable of holding a single character.

The two that declare arrays of 5 elements will work the same way to declare an array of 5 reals.  The three that declare characters of length 5 have no analog in other variable types.  The specific syntax of a subset of those three will compile, however, but will be used to select different *kinds* of reals, rather than denoting a character length.